# segfault in vkCmdDrawIndexed when creating command buffers for second time

Tags: c++, vulkan

Edit: 
Here is the output of valgrind:

```
==6785== 
==6785== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==6785==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xE0
==6785==    at 0xA138542: cvdescriptorset::DescriptorSet::ValidateDrawState(std::map<unsigned int, descriptor_req, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, descriptor_req> > > const&, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > const&, std::string*) const (in /home/user/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/lib/libVkLayer_core_validation.so)
==6785==    by 0xA0D9A06: core_validation::validate_and_update_draw_state(core_validation::layer_data*, GLOBAL_CB_NODE*, bool, VkPipelineBindPoint, char const*) (in /home/user/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/lib/libVkLayer_core_validation.so)
==6785==    by 0xA0EE4F3: core_validation::CmdDrawIndexed(VkCommandBuffer_T*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, unsigned int) (in /home/user/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/lib/libVkLayer_core_validation.so)
==6785==    by 0xA8B6F23: object_tracker::CmdDrawIndexed(VkCommandBuffer_T*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, unsigned int) (in /home/user/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/lib/libVkLayer_object_tracker.so)
==6785==    by 0xB3AD421: threading::CmdDrawIndexed(VkCommandBuffer_T*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, unsigned int) (in /home/user/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64/lib/libVkLayer_threading.so)
==6785==    by 0x13B147: VulkanRenderer::createCommandBuffers(ObjectInRAM*, ObjectInRAM*) (in /home/wobbi/git/Code/Implementierungen/Vulkan/VulkanTest)
==6785==    by 0x13F1FF: VulkanRenderer::mainLoop() (in /home/wobbi/git/Code/Implementierungen/Vulkan/VulkanTest)
==6785==    by 0x110716: main (in /home/wobbi/git/Code/Implementierungen/Vulkan/VulkanTest)
```

I somehow managed to get a segfault during vkCmdDrawIndexed in my Vulkan application. 
What I'm trying to do is i want to draw two objects. The first only once and the second object a variable number of times in different positions (without instancing). I get the different positions via pushConstants and everything works fine that far.

When a button is pressed i want to increase the number of times the second object is drawn, so i wait until the device is idle and then recreate command buffers with the new number of draw calls.

But during the recreation of the command buffers i get a segfault in:
vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffers[i], obj2->indices.size(), 1,0,0,0);

My code is based on Vulkan-Tutorial.com, so i just call the createCommandBuffers()-function again.

I allocated my pool with:
poolInfo.flags = VK_COMMAND_POOL_CREATE_RESET_COMMAND_BUFFER_BIT;

Any help on why i get the segfault would be greatly appreciated

Code:

```
void VulkanRenderer::mainLoop() 
{
    float lastTextureChange = glfwGetTime();
    float lastFPSUpdate = glfwGetTime();
    int numFrames = 0;
    int lastGPULoad = 1; 

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();

        //adjust camera values
        //if frames are further apart then movement between frames has to be faster
        float currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;  


        do_movement();

        updateUniformBuffer(glm::vec3(0.0f), 0.1f);


        if(lastGPULoad != GPULoad)
        {           
            lastGPULoad = GPULoad;
            recreateSwapChain();
        }

        drawFrame();

    }

    vkDeviceWaitIdle(device);

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
}


void VulkanRenderer::recreateSwapChain()
{
    vkDeviceWaitIdle(device);

    createSwapChain();
    createImageViews();
    createRenderPass();
    createGraphicsPipeline();
    createDepthResources();
    createFramebuffers();
    createCommandBuffers(&male, &cube); 
}


void VulkanRenderer::createCommandBuffers(ObjectInRAM* obj, ObjectInRAM* obj2)
{
    //check if old command buffers are still around and free them
    if (commandBuffers.size() > 0) 
    {
        vkFreeCommandBuffers(device, commandPool, commandBuffers.size(), commandBuffers.data());
    }

    commandBuffers.resize(swapChainFramebuffers.size());
    std::cout <<"creating new command buffers:" <<commandBuffers.size() <<std::endl;

    VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo allocInfo = {};
    allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    allocInfo.commandPool = commandPool;
    allocInfo.level = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY;
    allocInfo.commandBufferCount = (uint32_t) commandBuffers.size();

    if (vkAllocateCommandBuffers(device, &allocInfo, commandBuffers.data()) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to allocate command buffers!");
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < commandBuffers.size(); i++) {
        VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo = {};
        beginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
        beginInfo.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_SIMULTANEOUS_USE_BIT;
        beginInfo.pInheritanceInfo = nullptr; // Optional

        vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[i], &beginInfo);

            VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassInfo = {};
            renderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
            renderPassInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
            renderPassInfo.framebuffer = swapChainFramebuffers[i];

            renderPassInfo.renderArea.offset = {0};
            renderPassInfo.renderArea.extent = swapChainExtent;

            std::array<VkClearValue, 2> clearValues = {};
            clearValues[0].color = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
            clearValues[1].depthStencil = {1.0f, 0};

            renderPassInfo.clearValueCount = clearValues.size();
            renderPassInfo.pClearValues = clearValues.data();

            updateUniformBuffer(glm::vec3(80.0f, 80.0f, 80.0f), 10.0f);

            vkCmdBeginRenderPass(commandBuffers[i], &renderPassInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);          

                pushUBO.model = glm::mat4();
                pushUBO.model = glm::scale(pushUBO.model, glm::vec3(1.0f));

                // Submit via push constant (rather than a UBO)
                vkCmdPushConstants(
                    commandBuffers[i],
                    pipelineLayout,
                    VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT,
                    0,
                    sizeof(pushUBO),
                    &pushUBO
                );


                vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, graphicsPipeline);

                vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSet, 0, nullptr);                   
                //Binding vertex buffers                    
                VkBuffer vertexBuffers[] = {obj2->vertexBuffer};
                VkDeviceSize offsets[] = {0};
                vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffers[i], 0, 1, vertexBuffers, offsets);
                vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(commandBuffers[i], obj2->indexBuffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32);
                std::cout <<"bound index: " <<obj2->indices.size() <<std::endl;

                vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffers[i], obj2->indices.size(), 1,0,0,0);

                std::cout <<"before crowd cmd recording " <<std::endl;
                //render crowd
                vertexBuffers[0] = obj->vertexBuffer;               
                vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffers[i], 0, 1, vertexBuffers, offsets);
                vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(commandBuffers[i], obj->indexBuffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32);


                int drawCmdCounter = 0;
                while(drawCmdCounter < GPULoad)
                {
                     pushUBO.model = glm::mat4();
                     pushUBO.model = glm::translate(pushUBO.model, glm::vec3(drawCmdCounter*5.0f, 0.0f,0.0f));
                     // Submit via push constant (rather than a UBO)
                     vkCmdPushConstants(
                        commandBuffers[i],
                        pipelineLayout,
                        VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT,
                        0,
                        sizeof(pushUBO),
                        &pushUBO
                     );

                     vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffers[i], obj->indices.size(), 1,0,0,0);
                     drawCmdCounter++;
                }            

            vkCmdEndRenderPass(commandBuffers[i]);
        if (vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[i]) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to record command buffer!");
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to  StackOverflow. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make the question clear.

Comment: Do you have proper synchronization in place to ensure that you don't overwrite the command buffer while it's still in-flight? Also enable the validation layers and check their output for any errors. If you have proper synchronization and validation is clean, post a call stack,

Comment: ´void VulkanRenderer::recreateSwapChain()
{
    vkDeviceWaitIdle(device);
    //recreate swap chain

    createCommandBuffers(); 
}´

I call this function in my main loop when i notice that i need more/less draw calls. Is waiting for the device to be idle enough to make sure that no more command buffers are in flight?

Comment: Yes, a vkDeviceWaitIdle should be sufficient but is not advised as you completely stall the device (and all of it's queues). So try to avoid it at runtime and go with fences instead.

Comment: Ok, i will implement this when i find the time. 
I added the callstack before the crash and it seems to happen while the descriptor sets are evaluated. Thats very confusing because i don't change the desriptor sets after the initial creation

Answer (score 0):

From the call stack it looks like a crash inside the layers.

1) (Always) use [updated SDK](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home)! You know, I can see you are using outdated SDK. At the time of writing there's four newer versions and probably bambillion bugfixes.

2) Try running it with layers off. That would verify it is a bug in the layers.

3) If 1) does not help and with 2) you made sure it's the layers, then you may try [trunk version](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers) of the layers (or at least scan the latest commits for something relevant), and look up the existing Issues or report a new one.

4) Potentially you can use the debug versions of the layers in `SDK/Source/lib` by setting `VK_LAYER_PATH` variable. That would enable doing breakpoint/step debugging of the layer itself.